# ExtJS Exporting Only Selected Rows

Tags: extjs

How can I only export selected rows?

Below code exports all of the rows in the page, How can I filter out ones that are not selected before exporting?

```
 list.saveDocumentAs({
        type: 'xlsx',
        title: 'Account',
        fileName: 'Account.xlsx'
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating an another column with checkbox items, syncing checkbox markings of each row to that column and filtering by that column right before I export, then I reset the filtering.

Function ended up being something like this

```
onExportList: function () {
    this.getView().queryById('lisatradegrid').store.filterBy(function (record, id) {
        if (record.get('isSelected'))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    });
    list.saveDocumentAs({
        type: 'xlsx',
        title: 'Account Change',
        fileName: 'Account Change Requests.xlsx'
    });
    setTimeout(function () {
        list.store.clearFilter();
    }, 1000);      
},
```